# find the last_id in the current page

Tags: mongodb

Can somebody help me out how to find the **last_id** in the current page? I am displaying 50 records inside a table using the query `db.users.find().limit(50)`

I want the id of the 50th record of the page and want to use it in the bellow query:

```
users = db.users.find({'_id'> last_id}). limit(50)
```

Thanks!

Comment: check [mongo sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)

Comment: And `db.users.find().sort({ "_id": 1 }).skip(49).limit(1)`. But you are asking the wrong question and approaching the problem from the wrong way as well.

Comment: @yogesh OP seems to be asking about "forward paging" but in the wrong way of course.

Comment: Its a very basic question, but I want the last_id of every page so that I can use it further

Comment: @ Blakes Seven you are right!! I'm sorry for the bad approach

Comment: @UserAR FYI. The next question to yours directly asked about "forward paging" so I gave an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31243398/5031275. Got to that one before your comment was read.

Comment: @Blakes Seven, that is using php driver, could you let me know if there is any using pymogo??!!

Comment: The code given there is a basic JavaScript example. Python syntax is basically "identical" to JSON notation as is used. Variables and array pushing should be fairly simple concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your intent is to do **pagination** with MongoDB. We have better ways to do that. For instance:

```
//Page 1
db.users.find().skip(0).limit (10)
//Page 2
db.users.find().skip(10).limit(10)
//Page 3
db.users.find().skip(20).limit(10)
```

Change the skip value based on the page you are showing (i.e. (N-1) * 10).

[Learn more](http://blog.mongodirector.com/fast-paging-with-mongodb/).

Comment: Exactly @TechWisdom, but I want to do it on page scroll

Comment: Great @UserAR, so you need to query MongoDB based on the client's scrolling state. Just pass the server a consecutive number. If you are using Angular there are excellent plugins for this task.

Comment: Yes @TechWisdom, are there any JS or JQuery plugins for the same? If so, could you please share it? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, @UserAR. You have [jscroll](https://github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll) and [jquery-endless-scroll](https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll). Or google "jquery infinite scrolling"

Comment: @UserAR, You are welcome my friend. It would be great if you could mark  it as your answer. Thanks.