# Mongoose pagination with sorting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pagination

I'm having trouble to get my pagination with Mongoose and NodeJs working. In my collection I'm using the ids to create a pagination like so:

```
 var limit = req.params.limit ? req.params.limit : 1;
 limit ++; 

 if(req.params.start){
     var start = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.start); 
     Canvas.find().where({_id : {$lte : start}}).sort({"_id": -1}).limit(limit).exec(function(err, items){
           if(items.length > limit -1){
               var last = items.pop(); 
               items.push({next : last._id});  
         }
       });
 }else{
     Canvas.find().sort({"_id": -1}).limit(limit).exec(function(err, items){
         if(items.length > limit -1){
              var last = items.pop(); 
              items.push({next : last._id});  
         }
     });
 }
```

And this approach works really fine in this context. I don't want to use skip() [because of performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228169/slow-pagination-over-tons-of-records-in-mongo). I preferably like to use a similar implementation when I create mhy toplist of canvases.

Each canvas have votes, a number, that I like to sort by descending. But the problem is that then I no longer can use the ids $lte because that's not the order they come back in since ObjectId is [kind of like a timestamp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/) also.

Is there a way of using the next variable, as shown above, as a start in the next page selection or any other implementation without using skip or at least using it with ok performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate skip value for given record for sorted paging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242867/calculate-skip-value-for-given-record-for-sorted-paging)

Comment: I explicitly told that I don't want to use skip so why duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, as a little tweak to your code you could use `sort({ votes: -1, _id: -1})` and paginate using `votes` as the primary and `_id` as the secondary criterion.

Apart from that, if you're at a stage when you have so many records that `skip()` is really hurting, you can maintain a separate cache by bucketing ranges of votes. This will incur some additional maintenance in updating the cache on boundary crosses and so on, but will work pretty smooth once set up properly. It's really upto you to decide how you want to go forward. Might as well try both and see what works best for you.

Comment: Great! I will try it out later, today or tomorrow. I've read in a separate post about an implementation with skip() and that somewhere around a 1000 skips where noticeable. In my implementation that will mean that there will have to be 1000 posts with same amount of votes (if using skip), which is not impossible but highly unlikely. But I like the solution with two keys. Thanks.

Comment: This works like a charm. First I select only by votes descending, letting the start variable be optional. The second time I use the method described above to select first by votes, then by id.