# MongoDB pagination with document modified date

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I am implementing a stream of sort, which is storing data like below

```
{_id:ObjectId(), owner:1, text:"some text1", created:"2015-11-14T01:01:00+00:00", updated:"2015-11-14T01:01:00+00:00"}
{_id:ObjectId(), owner:1, text:"some text2", created:"2015-11-14T01:01:00+00:00", updated:"2015-11-14T01:01:00+00:00"}
{_id:ObjectId(), owner:1, text:"some text3", created:"2015-11-14T01:01:00+00:00", updated:"2015-11-14T01:02:00+00:00"}
...
{_id:ObjectId(), owner:1, text:"some text4", created:"2015-11-14T01:30:00+00:00", updated:"2015-11-14T01:31:00+00:00"}
...
```

Note that there is frequent bulk update, which means there can be more than 10-20 documents updated at the same time.

---

My aggregation query looks like this

```
db.stream.aggregate([
    $match: { 
        'owner': 1, 
        'updated': { $lte: '2015-11-14T01:30:00+00:00' } },
    $sort: { 'updated': -1 },
    $limit: 10
])
```

If there are more than 10 objects with same updated date my pagination will not continue.

for pagination I have last document of previous page 
I can extract `_id` and `updated`

Is it possible to do something like

```
$match : {updated :{ $lt: last_page_ele.updated} }
$sort : { updated }
$match : { `documents which comes after the last element in this order` }
$limit : 10
```

---

**Update:**

It is possible to use the method suggested by @Blakes Seven, i.e to store all the `seen` documents in a session array and use `$nin`. This was an obvious solution, but it screws up my front end behaviour. You cannot open multiple tabs, which will use the same session space used by the other tab.

Plus in my case storing 100s of items in RAM seems to be impractical and not scalable for lot of users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate skip value for given record for sorted paging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242867/calculate-skip-value-for-given-record-for-sorted-paging)

Comment: @BlakesSeven Unfortunately I cannot use session because of arch  constraints

Comment: It's not about "session" per se, but more about keeping values. You already said *"I have the last document from the previous page"*, and that is *part* of what you need ( and also implies storage between requests ). The other part as explained there is keeping the list of common `_id` values to the "same" value of the sort ( date ). All you really need other than filtering out the values greater/less than the sorted value are the other `_id` values for that same sorted value. That is what the answer explains. That's how you do it.

Comment: Comment too long. So it **is** the same exact question. With of course the same basic resolution.

Comment: I am getting last document from the client side (`next_page` token of sort). What if the common _id exceeds 100 ? in my case it is possible to have more than 100 items modified at the same time! which will return same 20 documents every time in a loop

Comment: The linked answer you are given is full of links to the documented operators used, I suggest you spend some time reading them. The `$nin` operator used accepted an array as it's argument. Yes it is meant to contain a possible "large" number of elements. That's the point.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll look into it