# Pagination with MongoDB in Node.js (With Sorting)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

Using suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js) and [here](http://blog.mongodirector.com/fast-paging-with-mongodb/), I'm trying to implement a scalable, paginating, stateless REST API in the following way:

```
//Page 1
db.users.find().limit(pageSize);
//Find the id of the last document in this page
last_id = ...

//Page 2
users = db.users.find({'_id'> last_id}).limit(pageSize);
//Update the last id with the id of the last document in this page
last_id = ...
```

It works in most cases, but the problem is I have to sort a list of videos according to view count and then try to paginate.

```
// Page 2
videos = db.videos.find({'viewCount'< last_view_count}).sort({viewCount : 'descending'}).limit(pageSize);
```

This does not work since there might be multiple items with same view count and some items will miss out when we do `'viewCount'< last_view_count`

Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate skip value for given record for sorted paging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242867/calculate-skip-value-for-given-record-for-sorted-paging)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in a state-less environment where each request can hit any of the servers in a cluster and run in isolation?

Comment: A session store or any kind of persistence is generally required for stateless requests. If you are not using cookie based sessions then you should be using a token in the request. The bottom line is the persisted store needs to be accessible to all worker nodes. That is a common practice in high-availability systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort and filter on a combination of fields that together uniquely identify documents. For example, sort on `{viewcount: 'descending', _id: 'ascending'}`, and filter on `{viewcount <= last_view_count, _id > last_id}`.

Comment: Good answer. Just wondering, is there any way to extend this to a two-way backward/forward pagination? Ex. being able to get both page 2 and page 4 while having the page 3 response?