# How to efficiently index for a query that uses $gt and $lt while doing a sort?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am trying to optimize the following query with MongoDB 2.6:

```
db.QuizResponse.find({
   createdAt: { 
      '$lt': new Date('Thu Mar 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)'), 
      '$gt': new Date('Jan 1 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)') 
   }
},
{ progress: 1, createdAt: 1, _id: 0 })
.limit(0...1000)  // The query will be limited in the real world
.sort({ progress: 1 })
```

My first instinct was to create an index on `createdAt` that also included `progress`, however I ran into problems with `scanAndOrder`. After reading these articles: http://blog.mlab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/ and https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/, I'm trying to create an index that will net me the lowest query time and not be a time bomb when the collection has a lot of documents.

I have setup the following index:

```
{
   "progress" : 1,
   "createdAt" : 1
}
```

But when I run the query with explain, I see:

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor progress_createdAt",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 66156,
"nscannedObjects" : 66156,
"nscanned" : 66156,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 66156,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 66156,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 516,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 272,
```

1. It's evaluating every document with `66156 nscannedObjects`
2. Its not using `indexOnly` even though all of the fields are covered by the query

I tried removing the `$lt` but leaving the `$gt` constraint, but get the same result.

Using a simple `createdAt` index is faster, but results in a `scanAndOrder`. Is this OK since I'm going to be limiting the query anyway? It's definitely much faster to let MongoDB run `scanAndOrder` vs. trying to create an index with the right sort order, that can also use the range query. As long as I cap the limit at a reasonable amount, it may never reach the memory limit?

Comment: There are a couple of cases where MongoDB can use more than one index in an operation, most notably there is when there is a `.sort()`. So it's best to define "two" indexes `.createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 })` and `.createIndex({ "progress": 1 })`. The "query" will use the index that is "prefixed" with the "createdAt" and the sort phase will use the "progress" index. That's most efficient.

Comment: Your real problem is with the sort. See [Calculate skip value for given record for sorted paging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242867/calculate-skip-value-for-given-record-for-sorted-paging/31243398#31243398) for a viable **faster** alternative.

Comment: Also read: [Compound Indexes - Prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) for the full explanation of why your current index is not optimal.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven. I can't actually use `skip` because I am using the Meteor framework and it would cause Meteor to fall back to a polling driver instead of an oplog based observation driver. Trading one performance hit for another I'm afraid. Will give that URL a read.

Edit: Will `explain` show if the query is using multiple indexes?

Comment: There is nothing there that cannot be done with meteor and your conclusion is not correct. The big performance hit would be allowing the collection you are "paging" to be published at all. Instead your requests should be a server side operation for each "page". Reactivity makes little sense with paged data.

Comment: I tried using an index on `progress` and one on `createdAt`. Mongo seems to prefer the `progress` index due to the sort, and doesn't attempt to use intersections. Only two things in `allPlans`: `BtreeCursor progress`, and `BtreeCursor createdAt`. Either way, its still at `66156 nscannedObjects`

Comment: @BlakesSeven This is a list of live data that must be reactive. I am allowing users to sort by a few different properties, and filter with a time range. I have implemented an infinite scroll pattern (with a maximum limit) for the pagination.